# why sudo delays 5s to 10s if WIFI is enabled? and how to fix it?

Tags: sudo, internet, lag, slowdown

run this in terminal with internet off:

```
while true;do sudo -n uptime 2>/dev/null;echo "`date`($((i++)))";sleep 0.1;done
```

now turn internet on (WIFI here).
The log will happen now every 5s to 10s...

How to make sudo ignore internet?

Also, why it behaves like that?

Obs.: ubuntu 22.04

PS.: I use `sudo -n uptime` to alert if the terminal has sudo access (I color it all in red). So I get that problem on every command I run in the terminal.

a log with the delays when WIFI is ON:

```
Fri  5 Jan 00:07:41 -03 2024(0)
Fri  5 Jan 00:07:47 -03 2024(1)
Fri  5 Jan 00:07:52 -03 2024(2)
Fri  5 Jan 00:07:57 -03 2024(3)
Fri  5 Jan 00:07:57 -03 2024(4)
Fri  5 Jan 00:08:02 -03 2024(5)
Fri  5 Jan 00:08:02 -03 2024(6)
Fri  5 Jan 00:08:13 -03 2024(7)
Fri  5 Jan 00:08:18 -03 2024(8)
Fri  5 Jan 00:08:18 -03 2024(9)
Fri  5 Jan 00:08:23 -03 2024(10)
Fri  5 Jan 00:08:28 -03 2024(11)
Fri  5 Jan 00:08:28 -03 2024(12)
Fri  5 Jan 00:08:34 -03 2024(13)
Fri  5 Jan 00:08:39 -03 2024(14)
Fri  5 Jan 00:08:44 -03 2024(15)
Fri  5 Jan 00:08:44 -03 2024(16)
```

when WIFI is OFF:

```
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:45 -03 2024(21)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:45 -03 2024(22)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:46 -03 2024(23)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:46 -03 2024(24)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:46 -03 2024(25)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:46 -03 2024(26)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:46 -03 2024(27)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:46 -03 2024(28)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:46 -03 2024(29)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:46 -03 2024(30)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:47 -03 2024(31)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:47 -03 2024(32)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:47 -03 2024(33)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:47 -03 2024(34)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:47 -03 2024(35)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:47 -03 2024(36)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:47 -03 2024(37)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:47 -03 2024(38)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:47 -03 2024(39)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:48 -03 2024(40)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:48 -03 2024(41)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:48 -03 2024(42)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:48 -03 2024(43)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:48 -03 2024(44)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:48 -03 2024(45)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:48 -03 2024(46)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:48 -03 2024(47)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:49 -03 2024(48)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:49 -03 2024(49)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:49 -03 2024(50)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:49 -03 2024(51)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:49 -03 2024(52)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:49 -03 2024(53)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:49 -03 2024(54)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:49 -03 2024(55)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:50 -03 2024(56)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:50 -03 2024(57)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:50 -03 2024(58)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:50 -03 2024(59)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:50 -03 2024(60)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:50 -03 2024(61)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:50 -03 2024(62)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:50 -03 2024(63)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:50 -03 2024(64)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:51 -03 2024(65)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:51 -03 2024(66)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:51 -03 2024(67)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:51 -03 2024(68)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:51 -03 2024(69)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:51 -03 2024(70)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:51 -03 2024(71)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:51 -03 2024(72)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:52 -03 2024(73)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:52 -03 2024(74)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:52 -03 2024(75)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:52 -03 2024(76)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:52 -03 2024(77)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:52 -03 2024(78)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:52 -03 2024(79)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:52 -03 2024(80)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:52 -03 2024(81)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:53 -03 2024(82)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:53 -03 2024(83)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:53 -03 2024(84)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:53 -03 2024(85)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:53 -03 2024(86)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:53 -03 2024(87)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:53 -03 2024(88)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:53 -03 2024(89)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:54 -03 2024(90)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:54 -03 2024(91)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:54 -03 2024(92)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:54 -03 2024(93)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:54 -03 2024(94)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:54 -03 2024(95)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:54 -03 2024(96)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:54 -03 2024(97)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:54 -03 2024(98)
Fri  5 Jan 00:11:55 -03 2024(99)
```

Comment: DNS resolution problems/delays?

Comment: why sudo ever wants to touch that stuff if I did not explicitly ask it to?

Comment: Something in your rules resolving host names?

Comment: sounds like you've got some NIS / Kerberos / AD / … set up, possibly checking for a security/authentication server that's not there, but failing quickly when there's no network. Or did you configure a special `askpass` program for sudo? Or maybe you have some network mount that's usualyl unreachable? There's also sudo_plugins, though they're rarely used, as far as I can tell

Comment: @MarcusMüller wow, as far I know I have nothing of that, at least not that I had configured myself, in other words, if there is anything like that, it came configured like that when I installed the OS Ubuntu 22.04. I just expect it is not a virus (rootkit), could be that?!?!? :O

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov could it be some app I installed that configured that? any grep tip to what I should look for?

Comment: perhaps check some system logs?

Comment: @JaromandaX if I run `sudo dmesg -T` in a loop, nothing new shows there, should I look for something specific? btw, the 5s delay still happens randomly.

Comment: `dmesg` doesn't show ALL system logs - look in whatever logs you have in /var/log

Comment: Wait, randomly? Not always under the condition "connected to network"? And not never under the condition "not connected to network"?

Comment: @ConstantineA.B. it happens some times while connected to internet. It happens like a few times in a row while connected to internet, and then it wont happen for a few times. I paste a log of the times on OP. It is somewhat random, I dont get what is going on :(

Comment: Could you confirm it *never* happens without network?

Comment: @ConstantineA.B. for a short time it never happens. whenever I am disconnected WIFI, it never happened when I hit enter on terminals. But I can run it for longer, check the delay and be sure if it never happens for a few hours may be, but I need to code a better loop there to check if delay is > 1s and then log it.

Comment: Don't worry too much. If it happens on Wi-Fi many times within 5 mins, but zero times without, that should be good enough for us. Thing is that I just really wanted to rule out any confounding variables like "time after login" or CPU load or anything that might correlate with being online, but is not casually connected

Comment: With that out the room, we can do more complex stuff: Can you install and run wireguard to check whether any network traffic is caused when you run sudo?

Comment: @ConstantineA.B. I read OpenVPN is safer? I am still learning about it and WireGuard. I need some time to understand what they do and how should I use them. NetHogs shows nothing special that could hint it comes from sudo. I guess WireGuard is to detect everything in detail trying to access the internet right? and also log it? If so, it will be useful. I will read more.

Comment: Sorry typo meant Wireshark. And no, openvpn is not safer. Whoever told you that...

Comment: @ConstantineA.B. I will test it later, looks interesting, it has a gtk package what may be nice to use, thx! but `Defaults !fqdn` already solved it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Ubuntu uses the same default settings for `sudo` as Debian, its `fqdn` flag is enabled by default.

The `sudoers(5)` man page suggests that DNS-related issues are possible when this flag is enabled:

> Beware that when using DNS for host name resolution, turning on fqdn requires sudoers to make DNS lookups which renders sudo unusable if DNS stops working (for example if the machine is disconnected from the network). Just like with the hosts file, you must use the "canonical" name as DNS knows it. That is, you may not use a host alias (CNAME entry) due to performance issues and the fact that there is no way to get all aliases from DNS.
>
> This flag is on by default.

The `fqdn` flag allows the use of fully-qualified domain names in the sudoers file's `Host_Alias` definitions and in the hostname field of sudoers user privilege specifications. But it also means `sudo` will have to figure out the canonical fully-qualified form of the hostname. If it is not listed in `/etc/hosts`, this will require DNS lookups.

Assuming you don't get your hostname from a DHCP server, you could add a line like this to your `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.1.1     main-hostname.fully.qualified.domain main-hostname [any other forms here...]
```

Alternatively, if you don't use hostnames in your `sudoers` definitions (as would be expected in a single stand-alone system), you might want to add this line to your sudoers file:

```
Defaults !fqdn
```

to disable the `fqdn` option.

Comment: the hosts file changed nothing but you foresaw that. The `Defaults !fqdn` instantly worked just after saving sudoers, thx!